# Use Laravel Eloquent to query a minimum number of related models with the same attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

It is not easy at all to explain the issue on a title so I'll try to explain with this example:

**Tables/Models**

- Transaction (id, subscription_id, billing_date)
- Subscription (id, user_id)
- User (id)
- A `Transaction` belongs to a `Subscription`;
- A `Subscription` belongs to a `User`;
- A `User` has many `Subscription`;
- A `Subscription` has many `Transaction`;

I would like to retrieve all the `transactions` which are related to a `subscription` which is related to the same `user`, but only if there are **two or more** `transactions` with a `billing_date` `==` **today**.

Basically I want to know if there are transactions related to the same user which are going to be billed today. This is what I have now:

```
$transactions = Transaction::
    whereHas('subscription', function ($query) {
        $query->groupBy('subscriptions.user_id')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
})
    ->where('billing_date', '<=', Carbon::tomorrow())
    ->where('billing_date', '>=', Carbon::today())
    ->toSql();
```

and I also tried:

```
$transactions = Transaction::
    whereHas('subscription', function ($query) {
        $query->groupBy('subscriptions.user_id');
}, '>', 1)
    ->where('billing_date', '<=', Carbon::tomorrow())
    ->where('billing_date', '>=', Carbon::today())
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second where clause is overrinding the first one, multiple where clauses can be passed as array :

```
->where([['billing_date', '<=', Carbon::tomorrow()]
        ,['billing_date', '>=', Carbon::today()]
        ])
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it's not that... I use where clause in that way elsewhere and it works perfectly, I guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the DRYest solution but you can make a second relation:

```
class Transaction {
    public function currentSubscriptions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Subscription')
            ->where('billing_date', '<=', Carbon::tomorrow())
            ->where('billing_date', '>=', Carbon::today());
    }
}
```

and then

```
$transactions = Transaction::has('currentSubscriptions', '>', 1)
     ->with('subscriptions')->get();
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your time but this not what I'm looking for: I want to get all the transactions related to the same user which are going to be billed today, but only if there are more than 2 for the same user. To know if a transaction is related to the same user I need to join the transaction with the subscription as it have the user_id field.

Comment: I've edited my answer, not sure if this is what you meant but take a look.

Comment: A `Transaction` belongs to a `Subscription`.
A `Subscription` belongs to a `User`.
A `User` has many `Subscription`.
A `Subscription` has many `Transaction`.
I'll add this to the answer, maybe it'll make it more clear.